# tfs throw TestFailureException

Tags: tfs

I have local tfs server.If build definition start execution unit test- the server throw error after execute test:

```
Handle Test Run Exception

If testException is NOT TestFailureException
Initial Property Values
Condition = True
F900548: An error occurred publishing the Visual Studio test results. Details: 'The  following test run cannot be found: 15944.'
Final Property Values
Condition = True

Set TestStatus to Failed
```

So, what it is? How can I fix it?

Comment: May the build directory doesn't contain test result.